# Formats export with variable names in SAS

Tags: sas, format

I created a format for a variable as follows

```
proc format;
   value now      0=M
                  1=F
;
run;
```

and now I apply this to a dataset.

```
Data X; 
set X2;
format Var1 now.; 
run;
```

and I want to export this format using cntlout

```
proc format library=work cntlout=form; run;
```

this gives me the list of formats in the library catalog. But doesnot give me the variable name to which it is attached. 
How can I create a dataset with list of formats and the attached variables to it?

So I can see which format is linked to what variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to look up the variables in a specific dataset, often PROC CONTENTS is faster than using SASHELP.VCOLUMN or DICTIONARY.TABLES, particularly when there are lots of libraries/datasets defined.

```
57   proc contents data=x out=myvars(keep=name format) noprint;
58   run;

NOTE: The data set WORK.MYVARS has 1 observations and 2 variables.

59
60   data _null_;
61     set myvars;
62     put _all_;
63   run;

NAME=Var1 FORMAT=NOW _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
NOTE: There were 1 observations read from the data set WORK.MYVARS.
```

Comment: HI, i did the samething. Thank you anyways for your reply.

Comment: I don't understand, doesn't Reeza's answer or mine give you an acceptable solution?

Comment: before you answered this I tried your same conecpt that triggered my mind. and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this for a specific library you can use the SASHELP.VCOLUMN dataset. This dataset contains the formats for all variables and you can filter it as desired.